# Why can't I provide NMinimize with initial points when minimizing over two variables but not one?

Tags: mathematical-optimization

Supplying initial guesses works for two parameters:

```
In[238]:= Table[{i, j}, {i, 1/10, 1, 1/10}, {j, 1/10, 1, 1/10}];
testtab = Flatten[%, 1];

In[240]:= NMinimize[(x + y - 2/10)^2, {x, y}, 
 Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> testtab}]

Out[240]= {0., {x -> 0.1, y -> 0.1}}
```

But not a single parameter:

```
In[236]:= footab = Table[i, {i, 1/10, 1, 1/10}];

In[237]:= NMinimize[(x - 2/10)^2, {x}, 
 Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> footab}]

NMinimize::parchange: Inappropriate parameter: 
InitialPoints -> {1/10,1/5,3/10,2/5,1/2,3/5,7/10,4/5,9/10,1}, changed to Automatic. >>

Out[237]= {0., {x -> 0.2}}
```

The latter seems like a straight-forward simplification of the first case, but yet it clearly doesn't like the initial points a supplied, even though they seem to be viable  (one of the guesses is even the correct answer). Now, I do get the right answer in the second case, but I have more complicated code minimizing over a single parameter where it doesn't give me the right answer because Mathematica isn't accepting my initial guesses.

Any thoughts? Thanks for your time as always.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Feed `"InitialPoints"` a list of 1D vectors:

```
bartab = Table[{i}, {i, 1/10, 1, 1/10}];

NMinimize[(x - 2/10)^2, {x}, 
 Method -> {"Automatic", "InitialPoints" -> bartab}]
(*  {0., {x -> 0.2}}  *)
```

Answer (score 6):

Because `NMinimize` needs initial "regions", not values.

According to the manual, the initial "guess" region (not value) is given as a constrain. (bold mine)

```
NMinimize[{x^2, 3 <= x <= 4}, {x}]
```

> In order for NMinimize to work, it needs a rectangular initial region
>   in which to start. This is similar to giving other numerical methods a
>   starting point or starting points. **The initial region is specified by
>   giving each variable a finite upper and lower bound. This is done by
>   including in the constraints, or {x,a,b} in the variables.** If both are
>   given, the bounds in the variables are used for the initial region,
>   and the constraints are just used as constraints. If no initial region
>   is specified for a variable x, the default initial region of is used.
>   Different variables can have initial regions defined in different
>   ways.

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationGlobalNumerical.html